# Java Spring Design - Real Time updates

Tags: java, spring

I have to develop a mock Commodity Market with some Commodities, and a subscriber to that Commodity can see its Asset Value in real time. Let me clarify with example.

Let us the say the Mock Commodity Market has 3 Commodities with per Kg prices as below

1. Wheat: $1.8
2. Potato: $2.9
3. Rice: $2.1

The mock Commodity market will update these prices very frequently say every 1s to 2s. That is the price of Wheat may change to $1.83 after 1300 ms, and Potato may change to $2.88 after 1185ms and so on. I am able to develop the mock Market without difficulty.

Now let us say there is a Person holding 12Kg of Wheat, 5.6kg of potatoes and 13.8kg of Rice, then I want to show his total asset value in real time. That is it should update the value as soon as one of the commodity price is changed.

I need help with how to design this project in Spring.

Comment: Can you please let us know what you have tried ? Also what is the specific step where you are stuck ?

Comment: Hi Deepak, I have been able to make the Commodity market. The basic approach that I am using is that Commodity Market has an Array of Commodities. Then the Market starts a thread for each commodity. The thread then randomly generates a time between 1s to 2s and then update the commodity price with some delta. I am also able to code the part where the Vendor has some assets. I am only stuck at part of real time update. That is suppose after say 1.4s the price of Potato changes, then what should I do to update the Asset Value instantaneously.

Comment: That's a very interesting problem

Comment: There are two approaches we can go ahead with

Comment: We can have observers, which looks for changes in some object and perform some operations when the things changes. For the same look at the observer pattern.

Comment: The second approach is to have a job which updates the value of the user's assets periodically. But in our case the accuracy is quite important and we cannot rely on a randomly running job to update the asset value.

Comment: The third approach is to not store a individual's total value. Rather calculate this when the user requests his value. For calculating the value, go over all the commodity he has and perform sum of their values.